# How to map Oracle.DataAccess to an older version?

Tags: c#, oracle, app-config

I encouterd a problem with my Oracle.DataAccess-Versions. My computer has both Versions 2.112.1.0 and 2.122.1.2 installed, but the server which should run the .exe only has 2.112.1.0. I'm pretty new to C# so I searched my way trough the internet but I couldn't figure out, what I exactly have to do.

I tried to modify my app.config but it doesn't seem right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
        <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342"/>
                    <codeBase version="2.112.1.0" href="FILE://Oracle.DataAccess.dll"/>
                </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add a reference to version 2.122.1.0 and set the specific version to true.

Or you may try to change the reference by config file, in 2.0 framework i use this syntax:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.111.7.0" newVersion="2.111.7.20"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: `<assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.1.2" newVersion="2.112.1.0"/>`

This fixed my issue :) And also copying the config file to the server...